# Perl SFTP password authentication issues using Net::SFTP::Foreign. Pyt error. permission deny

Tags: perl, unix, sftp, pty

I'm using Net::FTP::Foreign with password authentication. and I get error about pty and permission error. firstly, cannot connect to pty slave. secondly, Foreign seems not use password authentication mode. IO:Pty is installed. the machine is solaris.

```
Code:
my %args = (password => 'pwd', user => 'usr', port => 22, more => '-v');
log->info("Starting SFTP...\n");
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($O->{sftp_server}, %args);
```

is there any wrong with my script or any configuration issue on my server.

thanks

Log:

> warning: TIOCSCTTY failed, slave might not be set as controlling
>   terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device at
>   /usr/pkgs/Export/US/SunOS5.10_i86pc/lib/perl5/CPAN/i86pc-solaris/IO/Pty.pm
>   line 121. Error: could not connect pty as controlling terminal! ssh:
>   tty: node name or service name not known Uncaught exception from user
>   code: Unable to establish SFTP connection: SSH slave exited
>   unexpectedly with error code 255 at
>   /usr/pkgs/Export/OPS/SunOS5.10_i86pc/cbin/mkt_daily_new_issue_download.pl
>   line 162 at
>   /usr/pkgs/Export/US/SunOS5.10_i86pc/lib/perl5/CPAN/Net/SFTP/Foreign/Common.pm
>   line 103
>   Net::SFTP::Foreign::Common::die_on_error('Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x84cfa78)',
>   'Unable to establish SFTP connection') called at
>   /usr/pkgs/Export/OPS/SunOS5.10_i86pc/cbin/mkt_daily_new_issue_download.pl
>   line 162

Comment: Can you run the script under `truss` and post here the output or send me it by email (I am the module author). Be aware that passwords, logins, hostnames and IPs may be visible. You may like to replace them by dummy ones.

Comment: the script is called by system. my commond is /usr/pkgs/Operations/cbin/mkt_daily_new_issue_download.pl. inside is my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new( host => 'server_name', user => 'usr', password => 'pwd', );.  as your suggestion i change the command to 'truss /usr/pkgs/Operations/cbin/mkt_daily_new_issue_download.pl'. then it succeeds. i do not know the difference between the two. but using truss in the front solve the problem.

Comment: It may be a race condition on the Pty code, as using `truss` slow down things a bit. I will try to reproduce the problem myself. Could you post the version details for perl, Solaris, IO::Pty and Net::SFTP::Foreign?

Comment: thanks a lot. 
my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) 
Platform: osname=solaris, osvers=2.10, archname=i86pc-solaris
IO::Pty   $VERSION = '1.10';
Net::SFTP::Foreign   our $VERSION = '1.75';

Comment: Do you know where did that perl come from? (i.e. Sunfreeware, compiled there, etc.). The output from `perl -V` would also help.