# Net::SFTP::Foreign error - could not connect pty as controlling terminal

Tags: perl, unix, sftp, pty

This is based on [another question that was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087991/perl-sftp-password-authentication-issues-using-netsftpforeign-pyt-error-pe/) but not fully answered.

I am experiencing the same behavior as [user2621980](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2621980/user2621980). My error

```
could not connect pty as controlling terminal!
```

goes away when I run the script with truss.

Also, it is important to note that when I run the script on Server_A, it works fine. But when another script on Server_B invokes (via an ssh call) the script on Server_A, that's when the error occurs.

I would like to know if [salva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124951/salva) was able to reproduce this and/or if a permanent solution has been identified.

A few details about my environment:

- Server_A uname: "SunOS SERVER_A 5.10 Generic_150400-11 sun4v sparc sun4v"
- Server_A perl version: v5.18.1
- Server_B uname: "SunOS SERVER_B 5.10 Generic_150400-11 sun4v sparc sun4v"
- Server_B perl version: v5.8.7
- Server_A: IO::Tty / IO::Pty - version 1.11
- Server_A: Net::SFTP::Foreign - version 1.77

Here is the snippet of my code being used:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
use IO::Pty;
use POSIX;

## Enable debugging
$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = -1;

## Instantiate the variables
my ($action,$host,$user,$pass,$file,$ldir,$rdir) = @ARGV;

## Create the SFTP connection
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host     => $host,
                                   user     => $user,
                                   password => $pass);
$sftp->die_on_error("Unable to establish SFTP connection");
```

Here is the output from the debug:

```
#15593 1400766701.00000 new: This is Net::SFTP::Foreign 1.77
#15593 1400766701.00000 new: Loaded from /export/home/hccprod/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm
#15593 1400766701.00000 new: Running on Perl v5.18.1 for solaris
#15593 1400766701.00000 new: debug set to -1
#15593 1400766701.00000 new: ~0 is 4294967295
#15593 1400766701.00000 new: Using backend Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Unix 1.76_03
#15593 1400766701.00000 _init_transport: ssh cmd: ssh -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -l myusername my.ftp.server -s sftp

Error: could not connect pty as controlling terminal!
#15593 1400766701.00000 _init_transport: starting password authentication
#15593 1400766701.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766702.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766703.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766704.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766705.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766706.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766707.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766708.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766709.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766710.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766711.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766712.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766713.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766714.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766715.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766716.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#15593 1400766717.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
#15593 1400766718.00000 _conn_lost: _conn_lost
#15593 1400766718.00000 _set_status: _set_status code: 6, str: No connection
#15593 1400766718.00000 _set_error: _set_err code: 37, str: SSH slave exited unexpectedly with error code 255
Unable to establish SFTP connection: SSH slave exited unexpectedly with error code 255 at /export/home/username/bin/sftp_service_debug.pl line 31.
#15593 1400766718.00000 DESTROY: Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x17cc20)->DESTROY called (current pid: 15593, disconnect_by_pid: )
#15593 1400766718.00000 disconnect: Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x17cc20)->disconnect called (ssh pid: )
#15593 1400766718.00000 _conn_lost: _conn_lost
```

Here is the debug output with warnings turned on:

```
Unquoted string "vars" may clash with future reserved word at ./test_sftp.pl line 2.
"my" variable $cmd masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./test_sftp.pl line 24.
"my" variable $result masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./test_sftp.pl line 26.
* Calling remote script:
  ssh centralftp "sftp_service_debug.pl 'put' 'host' 'username' 'password' 'file' 'srcdir' 'destdir'"
#7284 1402514985.00000 new: This is Net::SFTP::Foreign 1.77
#7284 1402514985.00000 new: Loaded from /export/home/hccprod/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm
#7284 1402514985.00000 new: Running on Perl v5.18.1 for solaris
#7284 1402514985.00000 new: debug set to -1
#7284 1402514985.00000 new: ~0 is 4294967295
#7284 1402514985.00000 new: Using backend Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Unix 1.76_03
#7284 1402514985.00000 _init_transport: ssh cmd: ssh -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -l onyximport centralftp.pegs.com -s sftp

warning: TIOCSCTTY failed, slave might not be set as controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device at /export/home/hccprod/lib/IO/Pty.pm line 121.
Error: could not connect pty as controlling terminal!
#7284 1402514985.00000 _init_transport: starting password authentication
#7284 1402514985.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514986.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514987.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514988.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514989.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514990.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514991.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514992.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514993.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514994.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514995.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514996.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514997.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514998.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402514999.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402515000.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
#7284 1402515001.00000 _init_transport: waiting for data from the pty to become available
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
#7284 1402515002.00000 _conn_lost: _conn_lost
#7284 1402515002.00000 _set_status: _set_status code: 6, str: No connection
#7284 1402515002.00000 _set_error: _set_err code: 37, str: SSH slave exited unexpectedly with error code 255
Unable to establish SFTP connection: SSH slave exited unexpectedly with error code 255 at /export/home/hccprod/bin/sftp_service_debug.pl line 40.
#7284 1402515002.00000 DESTROY: Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x17cc20)->DESTROY called (current pid: 7284, disconnect_by_pid: )
#7284 1402515002.00000 disconnect: Net::SFTP::Foreign=HASH(0x17cc20)->disconnect called (ssh pid: )
#7284 1402515002.00000 _conn_lost: _conn_lost
```

Comment: run the script passing perl the flag `-w`, that would cause IO::Pty to generate more informative warnings: `/usr/local/bin/perl -w path/to/your/script.pl`

Answer (score 0):

Run the script on Server_A using some OS tracing utility as `truss` and post the output for both the working and the failing (running it via Server_B) cases.

You can send me the captures by email if you don't want to post them publicly.

As a workaround you can try calling Net::SFTP::Foreign from Net::OpenSSH, though you will have to install the real OpenSSH client.

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
my $sftp = $ssh->sftp;
```

The password handling code for both modules is similar but not identical.

Comment: Hi salva, thanks for replying.  The problem is that the second case only fails when I run it without truss.  As soon as I add truss into the ssh call, the script succeeds (this is currently my workaround).  Still, if you think it will help, I'll capture the output from that test case and send it to you anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: That looks like some kind of race condition. Enable debugging on the module and post the output: `$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = -1`

Comment: @user3646056: don't use comments for that. Instead, update your question with the information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Question has been updated.

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed your request to add the -w flag until today.  I've re-run with it and added the output above.  Thanks.